# how to show the orginal color of the button in a toolbar

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I had an application in which i am creating a toolbar to navigate through the web view .everything is working fine,except for the color of the button.when i am not enabling the button it is showing as the same color as the tint color of the toolbar.and when i enable it it is showing as white.but i need to present the button as it is.here is how i am doing it ,`

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;


    self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:215/255.0 green:215/255.0 blue:215/255.0 alpha:1.0];  
    buttonGoBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonTouchUp:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    fixedSpace.width = 30;

    buttonGoForward = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"forward_icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(forwardButtonTouchUp:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];



    buttonAction = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(buttonActionTouchUp:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *buttonContainer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:containerView];
    [containerView release];
    NSMutableArray *toolBarButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [toolBarButtons addObject:buttonGoBack];
    [toolBarButtons addObject:fixedSpace];
    [toolBarButtons addObject:buttonGoForward];
    [toolBarButtons addObject:flexibleSpace];
    [toolBarButtons addObject:buttonContainer];
    [toolBarButtons addObject:flexibleSpace];
     [toolBarButtons addObject:buttonAction];



    // Set buttons to tool bar
    [self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:toolBarButtons animated:YES];
```

`

how can i get the orginal color of the button for button enabled=NO;Can anybody help me

Comment: the simplest way is to disable the userInteraction of button

Comment: @Erik i did it .but it doesnt give me the orginal color of the button.thats the problem

Comment: can you post screen shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had made out a solution ,happy to share with all if anybody facing the same problem.

`[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

In this way you can give any color the barbuttons.

Answer (score 0):

The below link provide the whole code to change the color of UIButton in UIToolBar
http://charles.lescampeurs.org/2011/02/10/tint-color-uibutton-and-uibarbuttonitem